# Regex to Get Phone Numbers From String

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract phone numbers from a text string that can look like the following:

```
Some address at some street (123) 456-7890
```

This is the current regex I am using, however it doesn't pull the phone number from the string:

```
/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i
```

I'm not a regex expert by any means, so any help will be appreciated. I would like the regex to be able to recognize any US phone number format, if possible, for example:

```
(123) 456-7890
(123)-456-7890
123 456 7890
123-456-7890
etc...
```

Comment: What about numbers starting `+31` for instance? Or mobile numbers? Or people who just write phone numbers with no separators?

Comment: Looks like your regex is for matching emails :-/

Comment: …and what about `+1 123 4567890`. It is a terrible idea to parse telephone numbers using regexp. Each time you are thinking that you have covered all cases, a new format will appear from the hell of unwanted number formats.

Comment: @Aaron ... and badly at that

Comment: @CD001 it sure isn't RFC822-compliant ; I'd recognize [this monster](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) anywhere

Comment: Never do copy / paste a RegEx for use in production.

Comment: `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}) \d{3} \d{4}|(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{4}` would match your 4 examples and not much more (in particular it's long because it only matches balanced brackets and homogeneous separators).

Comment: Sorry guys I'm an idiot and pasted the wrong regex expression from elsewhere in my code. I've updated my post with the correct expression that I'm using

Comment: @Daniel What is the overarching goal of this task?  Are you doing a page scrape and need to find anything that _might_ be a phone number?  It seems to me that you are less concerned with validation and purely focused on extraction.  Do you want to err on the side of "over-matching"?  Do you want to include `ext 1212` trailing substrings or not?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm extracting data from resumes (name, email, phone number, etc.). Things like extensions don't really matter for this

Comment: @Daniel then you are saving the matched data to a database?  Are you eventually stripping all non-digit characters from the substring before storing?  (I would)  Knowing your greater mission can aid in providing the cleanest solution.

Comment: @mickmackusa Not at the moment. I'm just dumping the extracted data to a database. If this were for a production app, I most likely would, however this is only for my seminar project, so I don't see the point going that "complex" right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is "anchored", i.e. enclosed between the meta-characters `^`  and `$` which respectively represent the start and end of a string.

It would correctly validate a phone number, but it's improper for searching it in the middle of the string (since the number won't generally start at the start of the string nor end at its end).

Remove those two characters and you should be good (otherwise show us your PHP code).

Note that the regex matches more than the formats you listed, but since I'm no US citizen I'll assume it's expected.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/ZR4Mbb/1)'s a regex101 sample showing it works as intended once the anchors are removed.

Comment: Your linked pattern isn't very tight.  It matches the whitespace characters prior to the start of the phone number.

Comment: @mickmackusa it's OP's pattern without the anchors. I'm not familiar with the US phone numbering plan so I won't try to produce a regex that closely answers' OP need, I just helped him with the problem he announced. TBH I noticed this leading space problem and tried to fix it but to no avail. Tell me if you succeed, I'll add a revised version to my answer !

Comment: I was tempted to mark this question as a duplicate because there are many, many question on StackOverflow that pertain to `regex` and `phone numbers` and several that are dedicated to US phone numbers.  I am choosing to walk away from this page, because I think the OP is satisfied with the support provided for their small/temporary project.

Comment: Just to add on the exact expression used for above linked defined : (\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4} @For record purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex: `/\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]\d{4}/`

Example:

```
$re = '/\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]\d{4}/';
$str = 'Some address at some street (123) 456-7890 lorem itsum
Some address at some street (123) 456-7890 lorem itsum
Some address at some street (123)-456-7890 lorem itsum
Some address at some street 123 456 7890 lorem itsum
Some address at some street 123-456-7890 lorem itsum';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow.  Every time you post a solution, please always include some explanation of how your solution works and why it is advisable.  I am particularly concerned about why you are advising that the OP (and future researchers) should use `PREG_SET_ORDER` as the 4th parameter and `0` as the 5th parameter in your function call.  Do you know why you are doing it?  It is causing unnecessary output array bloat.  Please improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here I have used JavaScript you can use the below pattern in your PHP code.

```
<input type="test" id="phone" onblur="isValid(this.value)"/>

var phone = document.querySelector('#phone');

phone.onblur = function(){
    var pattern = /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/;
  if(!pattern.test(this.value)){
      alert('In valid phone no');
      this.value = '';
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83pccpuh/19/